# ArcGIS 10.2 Custom Geocoder outputs results with no geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding, display, null-geometry

I have a custom general single field geocoder that reads a meter number field attached to premise points. This meter number field is the only link between our premise points and corrosion data tables with location information.

I created this geocoder so that our corrosion team can geo-locate keypoints based on meter numbers. The geocoder works fine (the correct coordinates are generated and the correct meter numbers are matched) however, the geocoder does not output any geometry in the results, just data. I have verified the projected coordinate systems and the source data of the geocoder.

Could something be wrong with the parameters of my geocoder? Our temporary solution to this is to extract the geocode result table and simply display XY data.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the row, right-click and then click on flash, what happens?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did. I even started a new blank document and added the geocode result layer to see if it was a projection issue. Nothing. No geometry.

Answer (score 1):

1. right click to the Geocoding in catalog and open properties.
2. expand "Outputs".
3. Select "Yes" in Write x and y coordinates.
4. Use [Find tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-the-find-tool.htm) => Location tabs, instead of Geocoding toolbar.

[image]